# Azure DevOps reset state

Tags: azure-devops, devops

I am looking to build a demo utilizing Azure DevOps to showcase integration and functionality of an Analytics software. I am looking for a solution where the state of my pipeline gets reset whenever I end the demo. For example, if "a merge request" has been done during the demo, I would like the state ("merge request") to be reset every time the demo is restarted - it should come to a state where no merge request has taken place. If any "build" command has taken place, this should be reset too

I could so something like this using GitLab docket image, but I would like to do this using Azure DevOps please. Any ideas / thoughts would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you are seeing it in the wrong way, that's a tool made to keep history no to reset. Gitlab can not do that either, you would maybe recreate a full gitlab instance but it would not "reset" a merge request

Here is how I do my demo:
- either you scaffold a project which can take artifacts/repo as template => https://github.com/lgmorand/azuredevops-self-service-project-creation/tree/master/creation
- or you can create a demo project, and use azure devops demo generator to export it (it creates a zip) and to reimport it, it creates a clone within the same org. /!\ export is an hidden feature of this portal so I won't tell you how (but it's now opensource and if you look for "enableextractor" in the source code, you'll find how to use it ;-))

it all depends on your demo but I would go with the CLI solution and even if it's not perfect, it can greatly simplify the "reset"